# Drools guvnor, avoid evaluate and activate Rule by Name at runtime

Tags: java, drools-guvnor

I need a solution about disable Drools Rule by runtime.
I knew a solution by implement AgendaFilters Interface at [Drools disable a rule at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832778/drools-disable-a-rule-at-runtime) .
But Please Attention that rule although not FIRE but still be evaluated and activated.
So to improve Performance I need to disable evaluated and activated for the rule too.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling evaluation should not have any performance impact, unless the rules have been written to use eval(someJavaFunction()) where the Java code invoked is doing something it shouldn't.

If you wish to prevent a rule from activating in specific circumstances, then you can always write the rule to match on a specific fact and insert/retract/modify that fact to control it.